# HTTPS and AAM SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, ssl, https

I have set up a new site OOB with http and https , offloading SSL at F5. all is working fine I can access site from out side with https and internally ( by pass F5) with http. However Java Scripts any where on site for example edit page is responding. any help with this ? 
My AAM looks like this : 
[image]any help ?

Comment: **where on site for example edit page is responding** is it not responding?

Comment: if you go to site action and click on edit page it wont edit page for me. There is Page button on top left of team site ( next to Browse) that also not working. so any thing on the page that use JS seems like are not responding. Sorry cant add image in comment section.

Comment: Any reason you're using SSL Offloading instead of SSL Bridging? SSL Offloading is a significant security risk.

Comment: Some thing business decided to go with. After you advise the same on other thread , I looked in to this but could not find much information about this so trying to make this work for now. Feel free to share any link to support SSL bridging better then offloading. @TrevorSeward